# Jenkins build succeeds even if post build script fails

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I have created a jenkins build with a maven project. It build the jar using maven from a git repository and after that executes a post build script. The jar building is successful but sometimes, the post build script fails. Even after the failure of post build script, the whole jenkins build is marked as Successful. Why is it so ?

I want the jenkins build to be marked as failure even if the post build script fails.

Anything that I need to do ?

Comment: check your post buildscript returns proper exit code back to jenkins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with DevD, your post build step exit code must be wrong. If you use the Post build task, you can check an option to make the build failing if the task is not OK.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use another build step in place of post build action.
Is it sufficient solution for you?

Comment: The above solution did the trick. Ill try this solution as well. :)